# Error while trying to do setter injection in spring via beans

Tags: java, spring

Here I am trying to do setter injection of two properties

I have two interface / class pair - `dependency` and `dependecySecond`.

IDependency.java:

```java
public interface IDependency {
    public void printDependency();
}
```

IDependencySecond.java:

```java
public interface IDependencySecond {
    public void printSecondDependency();
}
```

Dependency.java:

```java
public class Dependency implements IDependency {
    Dependency() {
        System.out.println("Inside dependency constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void printDependency() {
        System.out.println("I am dependency");
    }
}
```

DependencySecond.java:

```java
public class DependencySecond implements IDependencySecond {
    DependencySecond() {
        System.out.println("Inside second dependency constructor");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void printSecondDependency() {
        System.out.println("I am second depedency");
    }
}
```

Now I have IGame / BaseBallGame interface / class pair.

IGame.java:

```java
public interface IGame {
    public void printDependency();
    public void playGame();
}
```

BaseBallGame.java:

```java
public class BaseBallGame implements IGame {
    private IDependency dependency;
    private IDependencySecond dependencySecond;

    BaseBallGame(){
        System.out.println("Inside baseball game constructor");
    }
    
    public void setDependency(IDependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }
    
    public void setDependencySecond(IDependencySecond dependencySecond) {
        this.dependencySecond = dependencySecond;
    }

    @Override
    public void printDependency() {
        dependency.printDependency();
    }

    @Override
    public void playGame() {
        System.out.println("Playing baseball");
    }
}
```

Now, at first I have the following bean code:

```xml
<bean   id="dependency"
        class="com.lonelychild.springdemo.Dependency">
</bean>

<bean   id="dependency2"
        class="com.lonelychild.springdemo.DependencySecond">
</bean>

<bean   id="game"
        class="com.lonelychild.springdemo.BaseBallGame">
    <property name="dependency" ref="dependency"></property>
</bean>
```

and I have following main code:

```java
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

IGame game = context.getBean("game", IGame.class);

game.printDependency();
game.playGame();

context.close();
```

It runs without error, but when I add "dependencySecond" in bean:

```xml
<bean   id="game"
        class="com.lonelychild.springdemo.BaseBallGame">
    <property name="dependency" ref="dependency"></property>
    <property name="dependency2" ref="dependency2"></property>
</bean>
```

I get

> illegal depedencySecond setter method exception

So how can I add the second property?

Comment: Stop using the old outdated xml configuration. Switch to the java based way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of your property is the problem. It must match with the property name in the class, so:

```xml
<property name="dependency2" ref="dependency2">
```

must be:

```xml
<property name="dependencySecond" ref="dependency2">
```

BTW: Stop using the old outdated XML configuration. Switch to the modern Java based configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am following a udemy lecture video where author starts with xml and then teaches the java way

Comment: @PayelSenapati ignore the xml way. you will never need it anymore